How to force 'Host' header using HttpClient with HTTP/2?
I have a need to have a 'Host' header and make a HTTP/2 request to a custom server which requires the header.
The header is present when I use HTTP/1.1 request but once I do DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0) it disappears, I am using mitmproxy to check it.
I have attempted DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("host", "somespecifichost"), but it is ignored with HTTP/2.
What can I try to enforce the header?

That "custom server" sounds like a broken implementation of HTTP/2, which the vendor should fix.

@JeremyLakeman, I cannot argue about that but it is a legacy piece of software no one is going to touch anytime soon, so I have to figure something out.

If you cannot force the client to send the Host header, your other option is to try to synthesize it on the server, before it reaches the application.
Depending on the server you are using, it may offer some "interception" mechanism that allows you to add headers based on some other element of the request.
In this case, you want to synthesize the Host header from the HTTP/2 pseudo-header :authority.
Another option would be to hit a reverse proxy before your server.
The reverse proxy can offload TLS, synthesize the Host header, and then call the server in clear-text HTTP/2 (or re-encode the request in clear-text HTTP/1.1) -- there is no need to re-encrypt, although you may.

I have considered that option but I am looking for an option to force it from the client. Surely, there must be something that can be done.
I also do not see :authority header in mitmproxy.
